# AppStore Rejection: IAP not Loaded (no network?)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

My App displays *Failed to Load* in IAP interface When it can't access the network.

Is there something wrong with these words?

I don't know if they see this with network or without network. I have tested my app on different devices, but I haven't seen this when it can access the network.

**Apple:**

*----- 2.2 -----*

*We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.0.2 & iPhone 5s running iOS 8.0.2, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.*

*Specifically, your application failed to load In-App Purchases. Please refer to the attached screenshot(s) for more information.*

**Screenshot:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR83n.png

Comment: "on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks" is written write there in plain English.  They tested it online.

Comment: They're saying that the iAP failed to load when they tested it on both WiFi and cellular.

Comment: I see these words, but just can't reproduce this issue online :(. So I doubt if they test it with blocking network setting. I have tested it on iPhone4, 4s, 6, iPad2, iOS 6, iOS 8.0, iOS 8.0.2. Maybe I should get one iPhone 5s to test.

Comment: Are you testing using debug settings / profiles? Something could be different between debug and release that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that It's because the IAP settings haven't been approved first. I doubted this and communicated to Apple then it's *Ready for Sale* now.

Maybe the IAP settings had been rejected before and I didn't know it. It need to be edited to *Wait for Review* again.